# How to use PathLocationStrategy on localhost?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular4-router

I'm working on an Angular 4 web app and I need to use `PathLocationStrategy` (not `HashLocationStrategy`).

The only problem with `PathLocationStrategy` is that when I refresh a page, I instantly get a blank page with 404 errors in the console... Which is normal with `PathLocationStrategy`.

Once on a server, I can fix that by redirecting the routes to point on index.html. But how to fix this issue on localhost when I launch my app with `ng serve`?

It would be ideal since I'm working in "livereload", because when I update a file, I get a blank page and I have to restart from the base path.

So is it possible to use `PathLocationStrategy` when working in localhost?

Answer (score 0):

`ng serve` take care of both Strategy. Locally I am using PathLocationStrategy

Comment: Yes me too, that's not the issue. The problem is when using it and refreshing a page. It doesn't work anymore (blank page) on localhost. That's the issue.

Comment: Are you getting any error, please verify your route configurations.

Comment: even on subpath like "localhost/user/login" ? It works for me on "localhost/user" for example, not on subpathes.

Comment: are you changing the url through route or through hard reload?