# Why does path location strategy not work with with ng serve

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

In my angular application, if I want to navigate to a path of a feature module via the adress bar of the browser or the page is reloaded via hot reload, I get an empty page.

When inspecting the page:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
// for runtime.js ployfills.js styles.js vendor.js main.js
```

My routes:
**localhost:4200/** (works), **localhost:4200/feautre** (works), **localhost:4200/feature/second** (doesn't work)

```js
// app-routing.module.ts
{ path: 'feature', loadChildren: () => import('./feature/feature.module').then(m => m.FeatureModule) },
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }
```

```js
// feature-routing.module.ts
{ path: 'second', component: SecondComponent }, // doesn't work with hot reload and adress bar
{ path: '', component: FirstComponent }, // works with hot reload and adress bar
```

The `base href` is set to `/` (`<base href="/">`).

My `build` and `serve` of `angular.json`

```js
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "aot": true,
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
      "src/styles.css"
    ],
    "scripts": []
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "2mb",
          "maximumError": "5mb"
        },
        {
          "type": "anyComponentStyle",
          "maximumWarning": "6kb",
          "maximumError": "10kb"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
    }
  }
}
```

Version: **Angular: 10.1.4** **Angular CLI: 10.1.4**.

I'm using `ng serve` to start the Angular Live Development Server. Shouldn't the dev server rewrite the URL of unmatched paths automatically to `index.html`?

Maybe this basic example will help, although it works here. I don't know if this is simply due to Stackblitz, but my imports, declartations are the same. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ased48?file=src/app/app.component.ts

### Edit:

I think this question [How to use PathLocationStrategy on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738574/how-to-use-pathlocationstrategy-on-localhost) addresses the same Issue, but doesn't offer a solution.

Same here [How to run ng serve with PathLocationStrategy while falling back to index.html when page is refreshed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863628/how-to-run-ng-serve-with-pathlocationstrategy-while-falling-back-to-index-html-w) with no solution

> By default, ng serve supports this. You shouldn't encounter this problem while running locally

Comment: Unmatched paths need to be handled by router with `**` e.g. `{ path: '**', component: NotFoundPageComponent }`

Comment: Already tried this, but i didn't help. According to other questions, index.html is searched for at `feature/second/` (http://localhost:4200/feature/second), which of course does not exist there. The solution was to rewrite all URLs that do not match to index.html. But in my case I don't use a "real" server but only the dev server to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out the mistake was quite stupid...

In my `index.html` file `<app-root>` was not surronded by a `<body>` tag. Although I do not know exactly why this causes this behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I wasted an hour for this. Faced this issue after upgrading angular to 13. I have no clue how you debug or found the root cause that the body tag is culprit. Your debug method might help more.

Answer (score 0):

as per your last comment you can use

```
{ path: '**/*', component: NotFoundPageComponent }
```

that would solve your problem

Comment: I put this into the `app-routing.module.ts`, but the `NotFoundPageComponent`was never displayed. Changing the path to `**` made the wild card route work for paths like `/not-existing`, but not `/not-existing/not-existing` . In the latter case there was again an empty page with the sam error messages as in th eproblem description

Comment: use ** with aot: false in angular.json for server

Comment: Still doesn't fallback to index.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
// for runtime.js ployfills.js styles.js vendor.js main.js
```

And this answer helped me to solve my issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69610410

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30894542)