# Angular CLI - ng serve --serve-path

Tags: angular-cli

I am trying to use --serve-path to serve my entire application under that path. For example I want my path to be `localhost:4200/foobar` I use `ng serve --serve-path=/foobar/`. When I then go to that url my application does not load and I get a blank screen.

Comment: It seems impossible to modify the folder of generated bundles (with ```ng serve``` command).The option baseHref modify the base url that you use when to call application into browser. The files of bundles are always positioned into root of application. In last version of Angular, the option ```--deploy-url``` doesn't work, because is deleted.
I'm trying to modify the folder of bundles (when I use ```ng serve``` command), but I don't try a solution. Unfortunately, the option baseHref is not a solution for this problem.

Comment: look at this  [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11755)

Answer (score 9):

Besides `--serve-path` option you need to specify either `--base-href` or `--deploy-url` options or your assets would have an invalid source URI. Without them your `index.html` file contains something like

```html
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script src="vendor.js" defer></script>
  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</body>
```

As you can see, all the assets have incorrect `/vendor.js`, `/main.js` and so on URIs instead of right one `/foobar/vendor.js`, `/foobar/main.js` etc.

If you'd use `ng serve --serve-path=/foobar/ --base-href=/foobar/`, that `index.html` will look like

```html
<head>
  <base href="/foobar/">
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script src="vendor.js" defer></script>
  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</body>
```

If you'd use `ng serve --serve-path=/foobar/ --deploy-url=/foobar/`, same `index.html` will look as

```html
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script src="/foobar/vendor.js" defer></script>
  <script src="/foobar/main.js" defer></script>
</body>
```

Both options are considered as [deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19195) in modern angular versions (however still working with current Angular CLI 12) and it is recommended to use builder configuration option inside `angular.json` configuration file instead:

```json
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/foobar/",
            ...
```

Angular documentation says that using [`baseHref`](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag) is generally a better option than [`deployUrl`](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-deploy-url).

Answer (score -1):

```
pushd /your/path/
ng serve
popd
```